# Fully Connected Layer Followed by LSTM Layer

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

How do i combine a Tensorflow Fully Connected  Layer, which is then followed by a LSTM Layer. My goal is to feed data of batch_size=batch_size, sequence length seq_length, and dimension 1. Target is 21 dim one_hot vector.

Here is the code i tried. It throws an error **Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for W_first line**. What am i doing wrong

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 20,1]) #Number of examples,number of input, dimension of each input
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 21])
W_first=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,num_hidden]))
out_1= tf.matmul(data,W_first)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)
val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, out_1, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to multiply `data` and `W_first`. The dimensions are not compatible.

Comment: Hello, then how do i add a fully connected layer for that type of input? (Time series data)

Comment: Maybe you can flatten it before multiplication? Or make your weight 3D

Comment: Hi, but ideally i would want to multiply each input in the sequence by same weights matrix, wouldnt making it 3d update each component differently during backprop?

Comment: Ah, then you can use `tf.tile` to clone the weights tensor